# Finding unique records, ordered by field in association, with PostgreSQL and Rails 3?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, arel

**UPDATE**: So thanks to @Erwin Brandstetter, I now have this:

```
def self.unique_users_by_company(company)
  users = User.arel_table
  cards = Card.arel_table

  users_columns = User.column_names.map { |col| users[col.to_sym] }

  cards_condition = cards[:company_id].eq(company.id).
    and(cards[:user_id].eq(users[:id]))

  User.joins(:cards).where(cards_condition).group(users_columns).
    order('min(cards.created_at)')
end
```

... which seems to do exactly what I want. There are two shortcomings that I would still like to have addressed, however:

1. The `order()` clause is using straight SQL instead of Arel (couldn't figure it out).
2. Calling `.count` on the query above gives me this error:

   > NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_sym' for
   >   #<Arel::Attributes::Attribute:0x007f870dc42c50> from
   >   /Users/neezer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:227:in
   >   'execute_grouped_calculation'

   ... which I believe is probably related to how I'm mapping out the `users_columns`, so I don't have to manually type in all of them in the `group` clause.

How can I fix those two issues?

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**:

Here's what I have so far that solves the first part of my question:

```
def self.unique_users_by_company(company)
  users = User.arel_table
  cards = Card.arel_table

  cards_condition = cards[:company_id].eq(company.id)
    .and(cards[:user_id].eq(users[:id]))

  User.where(Card.where(cards_condition).exists)
end
```

This gives me 84 unique records, which is correct.

The problem is that I need those `User` records ordered by `cards[:created_at]` (whichever is earliest for that particular user). Appending `.order(cards[:created_at])` to the scope at the end of the method above does absolutely nothing.

I tried adding in a `.joins(:cards)`, but that give returns 587 records, which is incorrect (duplicate `User`s). `group_by` as I understand it is practically useless here as well, because of [how PostgreSQL handles it](http://practiceovertheory.com/blog/2009/09/23/postgresql-s-group-by/).

I need my result to be an `ActiveRecord::Relation` (so it's chainable) that returns a list of **unique** users who have cards that belong to a given company, ordered by the creation date of their first card... with a query that's written in Ruby and is database-agnostic.  How can I do this?

---

```
class Company
  has_many :cards
end

class Card
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end

class User
  has_many :cards
end
```

Please let me know if you need any other information, or if I wasn't clear in my question.

Answer (score 4):

The query you are looking for should look like this one:

```
SELECT user_id, min(created_at) AS min_created_at
FROM   cards
WHERE  company_id = 1
GROUP  BY user_id
ORDER  BY min(created_at)
```

You can join in the table `user` if you need columns of that table in the result, else you don't even need it for the query.
If you don't need `min_created_at` in the `SELECT` list, you can just leave it away.

Should be easy to translate to Ruby (which I am no good at).

---

To get the **whole user record** (as I derive from your comment):

```
SELECT u.*,
FROM   user u
JOIN  (
    SELECT user_id, min(created_at) AS min_created_at
    FROM   cards
    WHERE  company_id = 1
    GROUP  BY user_id
    ) c ON u.id = c.user_id
ORDER  BY min_created_at
```

Or:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM   user u
JOIN   cards c ON u.id = c.user_id
WHERE  c.company_id = 1
GROUP  BY u.id, u.col1, u.col2, ..   -- You have to spell out all columns!
ORDER  BY min(c.created_at)
```

With PostgreSQL 9.1+ you can simply write:

```
GROUP  BY u.id
```

(like in MySQL) .. provided `id` is the primary key.

I quote the [release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-9-1.html):

> Allow non-GROUP BY columns in the query target list when the primary
>   key is specified in the GROUP BY clause (Peter Eisentraut)
>
> The SQL standard allows this behavior, and because of the primary key,
>   the result is unambiguous.

Comment: I tried your second method, and I'm still getting group_by errors: `User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "cards" ON "cards"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE ("cards"."company_id" = 6 AND "cards"."user_id" = "users"."id") GROUP BY "users".*
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "cards" ON "cards"....`

Comment: That's using PG 9.1.1, though I'm going to need a solution that works with PG 8.3, as that's what [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) runs.

Comment: With PostgreSQL 8.3 you will have to spell out all columns of `user` that you retrieve in the SELECT list in the `GROUP BY` clause. My answer was misleading in that regard. Amended. Version 9.1 would make your live easier here. You might want to use my first version to avoid that. Should be faster, too.

Comment: Neat, I think the query is returning the right result set now. I've got two more Ruby-ish beefs (see my updated question above), but I think the SQL is where it should be now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the insight to use min(column) as a variable opposed to grouping and ordering (which doesn't work with associations).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you need it to be chainable complicates things, otherwise you can either drop down into SQL yourself or only select the column(s) you need via `select("users.id")` to get around the Postgres issue. Because at the heart of it your query is something like

```
SELECT users.id
FROM users 
INNER JOIN cards ON users.id = cards.user_id
WHERE cards.company_id = 1
GROUP BY users.id, DATE(cards.created_at)
ORDER BY DATE(cards.created_at) DESC
```

Which in Arel syntax is more or less:

```
User.select("id").joins(:cards).where(:"cards.company_id" => company.id).group_by("users.id, DATE(cards.created_at)").order("DATE(cards.created_at) DESC")
```

Comment: Ahh, but I need the whole user record, not just the `id`. How can I do that?

Comment: You could grab the IDs then turn around and do another query: `User.where(:id => id_list)` or just wrap it in a sub-query like Erwin is doing below.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to do this in one query, if possible. Any thoughts on the two issues I have on my updated method above? Thanks for the help so far...